# Get string from between two characters

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I need to get  string from between two characters. I have this

```
S= "10:21:35 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |MAJ Registre mémoire"
```

and it have to return 4 strings each in a variable:

```
a=10:21:35
b=Manipulation
c=Mémoire centrale
d=MAJ Registre mémoire
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [`String#split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Since it accepts a regular expression string, and `|` is a special character in regular expressions, you'll need to escape it (with a backslash). And since `\` is a special character in Java string literals, you'll need to escape *it*, too, which people sometimes find confusing. So given:

```
String S = "10:21:35 |Manipulation |Mémoire centrale |MAJ Registre mémoire";
```

then

```
String[] parts = S.split("\\|");
int index;
for (index = 0; index < parts.length; ++index) {
    System.out.println(parts[index]);
}
```

would output

```
10:21:35 
Manipulation 
Mémoire centrale 
MAJ Registre mémoire
```

(**With** the trailing spaces on the first three bits; [`trim`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) those if necessary.)

Comment: This is  the best you can get

Comment: I would use the 2 arguments version of split, at least if one of the (last) fields could be empty, otherwise trailing empty strings will be discarded. `String[] parts = S.split("\\|", 4);` or `String[] parts = S.split("\\|", -1);`

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = " 10:21:35   |  Manipulation |  Mémoire centrale |   MAJ Registre mémoire   ";
String[] split = s.trim().split("\\s*\\|\\s*",-1); //trim and split
```

Comment: This ditches the trailing spaces, except for the last column.

Comment: better supply the 2nd argument to split or risk missing an empty trailing field.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils has about 14 variants of the split() method.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of each column is varient, use the examples given here with the `split` method.

However, if you have a fixed-sized file format `substring` will be a much better option. If you look at the implementation of `substring` (Java 5 and above if I recall correctly) - you can see that it has an O(1) to create the new strings, whereas `split` uses a regex which is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
String[] s = "10:21:35 |Manipulation |Mémoire centrale |MAJ Registre mémoire".split("\\|");
```

There's also method `trim()` which removes trailing spaces from the strings.

Comment: No, that returns a large array of single-character strings. As I said in my answer, `|` is a special character in regular expressions, and `String#split` uses a regular expression string.

Comment: You're right, you have to escape the "|" with two back-slashes. I didn't run my code before posting it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Like in other answers I suggest you using split() method to separate your string but remeber to use trim if you won't have spaces after parts, like this:

```
S= "10:21:35 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |MAJ Registre mémoire"    
String splitted[] = S.split("\\|");
String a = splitted[0].trim();
String b = splitted[1].trim();
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use string.substring and get the required output as

```
string a =s.substring(0,8)
```

Like this u can assign for the one you want