# get string from between characters

Tags: java, algorithm, string, character

i have a String

```
S=

"Apprenant: User1


Temps    |Activité           |Sous Activité      |Action             

12:32:02 |Demonstration      |                   |

12:32:05 |Démonstration      |Mémoire centrale   |Inialisation

12:32:06 |Démonstration      |                   |Chargement

12:32:07 |Démonstration      |                   |Inst Suiv

12:32:11 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |

12:32:15 |Manipulation       |Unité de commande  |

12:32:17 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |

12:32:20 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |Vider la mémoire "
```

and I have to parse it and return 4 strings (each in a variable) as follows:

```
a=12:32:02

b=Demonstration

 c=" "

 d=" "

a=12:32:05

b=Demonstration

c=Mémoire centrale 

d=Inialisation

.............
................ until the end
```

my code :

```
while( S != null)
{
      str =S.readLine(); // the text is in a TextArea


     String splitted[] = str.split("\\|");

String a = splitted[0].trim();

String b = splitted[1].trim();

String c = splitted[2].trim();

String d = splitted[3].trim();

System.out.println("a="+a);

System.out.println("b="+b);

System.out.println("c="+c);

System.out.println("d="+d);


}
```

but it won't work

and the 5 first lines of S are not in consideration (i don't know how to do it)

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between this question and your earlier one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604498/get-string-from-between-two-characters to which you accepted an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't work"? What does it do, and how exactly does that differ from what you want it to do? Is your problem really with the string-splitting or with ignoring the first five lines?

Comment: Do you need to parse the first five lines, or can you just ignore them (using `S.readLine()` 5 times in a row)?

Comment: ignore the 5 first lines

Comment: how can i ignore the 5 first lines ???? and the other problem when a=" " , i didn't treat this case in my code

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to ignore the first five lines, call `S.readLine()` five times. Each time you call it, it will read (and discard) a line of text from the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not enough:

```
str.split("|");
```

?

And

```
int counter = 0;
while(...){
    counter += 1;
    if (counter<=5) continue;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string `s` is structured in multiple lines, so you have to (1) split on `\n`, (2) skip the first 5 rows, (3) split each row on `\\|`, and (4) assign variables when data is available. Here is a sample code that should give you an idea

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = 
        "Apprenant: User1\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Temps    |Activité           |Sous Activité      |Action\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:02 |Demonstration      |                   |\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:05 |Démonstration      |Mémoire centrale   |Inialisation\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:06 |Démonstration      |                   |Chargement\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:07 |Démonstration      |                   |Inst Suiv\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:11 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:15 |Manipulation       |Unité de commande  |\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:17 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |\n" +
        "\n" +
        "12:32:20 |Manipulation       |Mémoire centrale   |Vider la mémoire\n";

    String[] rows = s.split("\n");
    for (int i = 5; i < rows.length; i++) {
        String[] sections = rows[i].split("\\|");
        if (sections.length > 1) {
            String a = sections[0].trim();
            String b = "";
            String c = "";
            String d = "";
            if (sections.length == 2)
                b = sections[1].trim();
            if (sections.length == 3);
                c = sections[2].trim();
            if (sections.length == 4)
                d = sections[3].trim();
            System.out.println("a = " + a + "; b = " + b + 
                    "; c = " + c + "; d = " + d);
        }
    }

}
```

and that produces the following output:

```
a = 12:32:02; b = ; c = ; d = 
a = 12:32:05; b = ; c = Mémoire centrale; d = Inialisation
a = 12:32:06; b = ; c = ; d = Chargement
a = 12:32:07; b = ; c = ; d = Inst Suiv
a = 12:32:11; b = ; c = Mémoire centrale; d = 
a = 12:32:15; b = ; c = Unité de commande; d = 
a = 12:32:17; b = ; c = Mémoire centrale; d = 
a = 12:32:20; b = ; c = Mémoire centrale; d = Vider la mémoire
```